# How can I have tcpdump write to file and standard output the appropriate data?

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I want to have `tcpdump` write raw packet data into a file and also display packet analysis into standard output as the packets are captured (by analysis I mean the lines it displays normally when `-w` is missing).
Can anybody please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Here's a neat way to do what you want:

```
tcpdump -w - -U | tee somefile | tcpdump -r -
```

What it does:

- `-w -` tells `tcpdump` to write binary data to `stdout`
- `-U` tells `tcpdump` to write each packet to stdout as it is received, rather than buffering them and outputting in chunks
- `tee` writes that binary data to a file AND to its own `stdout`
- `-r -` tells the second `tcpdump` to get its data from its `stdin`

Comment: Using this technic, WireShark has complained of some of the files claiming that the last packet is incomplete. I guess tcpdump would unbuffer and write all data before ending, but, in case it doesn't,  -U option may be useful here. From the man page: ` Use the -U flag to cause packets to be written as soon as they are received.`. (trying not to lose any buffered/still-not-written-to-file packet when tcpdump is killed).  I haven't had a change to confirm that, though.

Comment: Why can't it be `tcpdump host <IP> | tee /tmp/output`. This avoids a second tcpdump that you are using at the end. Right ?

Comment: @deppfx That would work, at the cost of only saving the text. `-w` causes `tcpdump` to write the data in the standard binary format.

Comment: stdout has buffer, how to flush stdout?

Comment: @cnicutar This is genius. I like it. I'm using with options `-U` for packet buffered for printing per packet, `-n` for not converting IP addresses and ports to names. After modifications my command is `tcpdump <capture filter args here> -w - | tee filename.$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%Z.%H.%M.%S).pcap | tcpdump -r -` part with `$(<date +strftime>)` provides timestamp which we can't get otherwise since we are writing to `STDOUT` with `-w` . I know the part other than `-U` is not relevant to question, but putting it here in case anyone would like to use.

Comment: Without using `-U` the generated pcap file could be corrupted.

Comment: @cnicutar Thanks, still useful  in 2017!

Comment: @sdkks that was brilliant!

tcpdump -i eth0 port 22 and not host 172.30.247.4 -U -w - | tee capture.pcap |tcpdump -r -

God Bless stackoverflow!

Answer (score 26):

Since tcpdump <del>4.9.3</del> 4.99.0, the `--print` option can be used:

```
tcpdump -w somefile --print
```

```
Wednesday, December 30, 2020, by mcr@sandelman.ca, denis and fxl.
  Summary for 4.99.0 tcpdump release
    [...]
    User interface:
      [...]
      Add --print, to cause packet printing even with -w.
```

Comment: Does not work for me on ubuntu 20.04 tcpdump 4.9.3 libpcap 1.9.1: `tcpdump: unrecognized option '--print'`. It does with upstream git version of tcpdump.

Comment: @cdleonard, Indeed, it's actually available since 4.99.0. I amended my answer.

Comment: Sadly 4.9.3 is the latest version for ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This only prints the binary

Answer (score -1):

```
tcpdump ${ARGS} &
PID=$!
tcpdump ${ARGS} -w ${filename}
kill $PID
```

Answer (score -1):

**tcpdump > output.txt** if you are looking to save the output into a file in text format.

Use **sudo** if permission issues are there.

My exp, the data gets written continuously.

Answer (score -2):

If you want a way to do it without running tcpdump twice, consider:

```
sudo tcpdump port 80 -w $(tty) | tee /tmp/output.txt
```

From the interactive command prompt you could use `$TTY` instead of `$(tty)` but in a script the former wouldn't be set (though I'm not sure how common it is to run tcpdump in a script).

Side-note: it's not very Unix-y the way tcpdump by default makes you write to a file. Programs should by default write to stdout. Redirection to a file is already provided by the shell constructs. Maybe there's a good reason tcpdump is designed this way but I don't know what that is.

Comment: The `-w` output is binary, so this is not very useful.